# @abstract class - jsDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Hi there :) I know that it is ok to do something like that with jsDoc:

```
/**
 * @class
 */
function Implementator() {
    if (this instanceof Implementator) {
        throw new Error('Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.');
    }
}



/**
 * @abstract
 */
Implementator.prototype.react = function() {
    throw new Error('Not implemented.');
};
```

Here only a method is tagged as an abstract entity.

But can we add @abstract tag to Implementator class (function constructor) itself like this:

```
/**
 * @class 
 * @abstract
 */
function Implementator() {
    if (this instanceof Implementator) {
        throw new Error('Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.');
    }
}
```

I mean, I know it's doable and, in fact, jsDoc documentation generator adds *(abstact)* to the name of the class. But can that be added without any complications? Would such notation still be regarded as adhering to jsDoc convention?